# Generating an attribution list for dependencies included by react-native in app bundle

Tags: react-native

In order to ship a react-native app, we need to generate an attribution list which includes all of the dependencies shipped in our app bundle. One challenge is that React Native itself has a number of dependencies and it doesn't distinguish between dependencies used only at build time and dependencies that actually get put into the app's bundle. Only the latter kind of dependencies are important for our attribution list. It's also important to distinguish between dependencies which get put into the iOS app bundle vs the Android app bundle.

I figure somebody who has shipped a React Native app must have encountered this problem. Can anyone offer some guidance here?

- Has Facebook compiled a list of the dependencies React Native uses at build time vs the ones it includes in the app bundle?
- Does React Native's packager or some other tool have the ability to emit this information?

Comment: did you  do anything regarding this?